# MapIcon & Route - MapIcon disappears when in route

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, here-api

I'm trying to create an app which has a map, an MapIcon that "follows" the user current location and displays a simple walking route from A to B.

Currently I'm testing this on a WP8.1 emulator and everything works just great, unless I try to "walk" on the displayed route. The icon disappears and if I leave the route, the icon appears again.

Below there's the code related to this operations and some screenshots that shows the unexpected result.

The locations are hidden for privacy reasons.

```
Private geolocator As New Geolocator

Public Async Function IniciarGPS() As Task
    map.Language = "pt-PT"

    Dim waypoints As New List(Of Geopoint)
    waypoints.Add(New Geopoint(New BasicGeoposition With {
        .Latitude = 0.0,
        .Longitude = -0.0
    }))
    waypoints.Add(New Geopoint(New BasicGeoposition With {
        .Latitude = 0.0,
        .Longitude = -0.0
    }))
    Dim r As MapRouteFinderResult = Await MapRouteFinder.GetWalkingRouteFromWaypointsAsync(waypoints)
    If r.Status = MapRouteFinderStatus.Success Then
        Dim route As MapRoute = r.Route
        Dim mapRouteView As New MapRouteView(route)
        mapRouteView.RouteColor = Colors.Black
        map.Routes.Add(mapRouteView)
    End If

    geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High
    geolocator.MovementThreshold = 10

    AddHandler geolocator.PositionChanged, AddressOf geolocator_PositionChanged
End Function

Private mIcon As MapIcon = Nothing
Private Async Sub geolocator_PositionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PositionChangedEventArgs)
    Await map.TrySetViewAsync(e.Position.Coordinate.Point, 18, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Bow)

    Await Me.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
        Sub()
            If mIcon Is Nothing Then
                mIcon = New MapIcon()
                mIcon.Image =
                    RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(
                        New Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Map/map_icon.png")
                    )
                mIcon.Title = "EU"
                mIcon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = New Point(0.5, 0.5)
                map.MapElements.Add(mIcon)
            End If

            mIcon.Location = New Geopoint(New BasicGeoposition() With {
                .Latitude = e.Position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude,
                .Longitude = e.Position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude
            })
        End Sub)
End Sub
```

## Showing correctly

[image: Showing correctly]

## MapIcon not showing when on route defined

[image: MapIcon not showing when on route defined]

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem could be the Z-Ordering, and as there are no functions to change the z-ordering, you would need to do it by adding the objects in right order.

Thus can you see whether it helps if you remove & delete the person icon from the map when starting to make the route, and construct & add it back once you have added the route into the Map. This would ensure that the icon would be drawn on top of the route object.

Gotta admit that I did never check this option with route objects, thus if it fails still, then I would experiment trying to draw the route leg-by-leg using polylines, then at least it should work exactly right.

Comment: That's one thing that I have to try. Currently, I'm recalculating the route on every position changed so that the beginning of the route is the current location of the user. I'll have to try to wait for the route to draw and then after that draw the MapIcon. Thanks for the idea, I'll post the results once I'll get the time.